# How to create new element and render data each time the data is fetched in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I am new to react and I need to render and list data fetched from firebase to the html I tried doing this,

```js
const Music = ({ match }) => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState(null)
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const [pfp, setPfp] = useState(null)
    const { params: { uID } } = match;
useEffect(()=>{  firebase.database().ref("users/"+uID+"/public/songs/").on("value", (snapshot)=>{
            var musics = snapshot.val()
            Object.values(musics).forEach((value)=>{ 
            //I need to render this title each and create new li
                setTitle(<li>{value.title}</li>)
                
            })
        })    
    }, [])
    
    return(
        <>
            
            <Nav />
            <div id = "profile" className = "main">
                <div class = "profile-container">
                    <div className = "cover-pic">
                        <img src = "" />
                        <div className = "pfp">
                            <img src = {pfp} height = "100" width = "100"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className = "User-Name">
                            <h1>{user}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "tabsContainer">
                    <div class = "tabs-holder">
                    <NavLink to = {"/u/"+uID+"/music"}><button><span>Music</span></button></NavLink>
                        <button><span>Playlist</span></button>
                        <button><span>About</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
               
                <div class = "music-content-container">
                    <div class = "music-box">
                        <div class = "user-musics">
                            <ul>
                            //the title should rendered over here
                                {title}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <Header />
   )
}
```

but it only renders one element. While there are 5 elements in my database. How to fix/ do this?
how to make the program create all 5

tags and render the data?

Answer (score 1):

Don't rendere stuff in useEffect, just use it to add logic and set state:

```
const Music = ({ match }) => {
    const [musics, setMusics] = useState([])
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const [pfp, setPfp] = useState(null)
    const { params: { uID } } = match;
useEffect(()=>{  
     
        firebase.database()
        .ref("users/"+uID+"/public/songs/")
         .on("value", (snapshot)=>{
            var musics = snapshot.val()
            //not sure how music obj is , just set it as an array of something
            setMusics(musics)
        })    
    }, [])
    
    return(
        <>
            
            <Nav />
            <div id = "profile" className = "main">
                <div class = "profile-container">
                    <div className = "cover-pic">
                        <img src = "" />
                        <div className = "pfp">
                            <img src = {pfp} height = "100" width = "100"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className = "User-Name">
                            <h1>{user}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "tabsContainer">
                    <div class = "tabs-holder">
                    <NavLink to = {"/u/"+uID+"/music"}><button><span>Music</span></button></NavLink>
                        <button><span>Playlist</span></button>
                        <button><span>About</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
               {musics &&
                <div class = "music-content-container">
                    <div class = "music-box">
                        <div class = "user-musics">
                            <ul>
                          {musics.map((el,key)=><li>{el.title}</li>) }}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>}

            </div>

            <Header />
   )
}
```

Comment: it says Cannot read property 'map' of null

Comment: updated, btw as i said i don't know how musics is strucured

Comment: this is also an easy check, you could easy fix it

Comment: idk why its not working any other way of fetching data from firebase and rendering?