# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

Hi guys i am new to react js and It keeps on saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react.js, even tho its not undefined.

```js
//my variables    
    const [musics, setMusics] = useState()
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const [pfp, setPfp] = useState(null)
    const { params: { uID } } = match;
    var userName;
    var musicArray = [];
//use effect so it does not infinite loop     
 useEffect(()=>{   firebase.database().ref("users/"+uID+"/public/songs/").on("value", (snapshot)=>{
            var music = snapshot.val()
            //gets title of each songs
            Object.values(music).forEach((value)=>{  
                musicArray.push(value.title)//pushes value to array
                setMusics(musicArray)//sets that array to musics
                
            })
        })    
    }, [])
    
    return(
           .....
          <div class = "music-content-container">
                    <div class = "music-box">
                        <div class = "user-musics">
                            <ul>
                            //says TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined even tho its defined
                                {musics.map((name)=>{   
                                    return <li>{name}</li>
                                })}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         .....
            )
```

how do I fix this issue? is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create new element and render data each time the data is fetched in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167643/how-to-create-new-element-and-render-data-each-time-the-data-is-fetched-in-react)

Comment: duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167643/how-to-create-new-element-and-render-data-each-time-the-data-is-fetched-in-react/65167700#65167700 with already the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you define the state using `useState` for `musics`, you don't specify an initial value. Therefore, ReactJS doesn't know what type `musics` is.

The good practice is to always provide an initial state when using `useState`. In your case, it would be simply providing an empty array.

```js
const [musics, setMusics] = useState([])
```

I would even go further and rename the `musics` to something like `tracks` as this is more readable.

As a further refactoring in your code, I'd avoid using `var` and instead define variables with either `const` if it's not going to be changed or `let` if you expect to re-assign it.

I also noticed that in your `useEffect` you don't provide values for the dependency array for `musicArray` and `uID` as these are declared outside of `useEffect`. To avoid unnecessary re-renders, always provide external values in the dependency array. This way, the `useEffect` will be triggered when the values in the dependency array change.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   ...
  }, [musicArray, uID]);
```

Also, when using React, instead of `class` in your JSX use `className` as that's what React uses to map it to HTML `class` attribute. It's just one of React things that you need to remember.

So in your JSX you would write something like this

```js
<div className="music-content-container">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it will really help me out as i am beginner :)

Comment: the useEffect tip you gave me solved the problem that i was trying to solve for 30min

Comment: when i do
useEffect(() => {
   ...
  }, [musicArray, uID]);

it creates an infinite loop errr Maximum update depth exceeded

Comment: I'd extract the firebase data fetch into its own function and call it inside `useEffect` while also adding the function to the dependency array.

Answer (score 9):

The initial value of `musics` state is undefined. You should give initial value like this.

```js
const [musics, setMusics] = useState([])
```

Comment: thank you it works now, but idk why it only renders the first index of the array

Comment: It seems like there's wrong logic on your code for getting values from firebase

Comment: can you teach me how to do it? or suggest me some videos

Answer (score 1):

It is null when the component first renders until the useEffect sets the data. I would initialize it to an empty array in useState.